# Problem with 2d rotation in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rotation

I have a function to perform sprite rotation :

```
void Sprite::rotateSprite(float angle){
    //Making an array of vertices - 6 for 2 triangles

    Vector2<gamePos> halfDims(_rect.w / 2, _rect.h /2);

    Vector2<gamePos> bl(-halfDims.x,-halfDims.y);
    Vector2<gamePos> tl(-halfDims.x,halfDims.y);
    Vector2<gamePos> br(halfDims.x,-halfDims.y);
    Vector2<gamePos> tr(halfDims.x,halfDims.y);


    bl = rotatePoint(bl,angle) + halfDims;
    br = rotatePoint(br,angle) + halfDims;
    tl = rotatePoint(tl,angle) + halfDims;
    tr = rotatePoint(tr,angle) + halfDims;

    /**
        1st triangle
    **/

    //Top right
    _dataPointer.vertices[0].setPosition(_rect.x+tr.x,_rect.y+tr.y);

    //Top left
    _dataPointer.vertices[1].setPosition(_rect.x+tl.x,_rect.y+tl.y);

    //Bottom left
    _dataPointer.vertices[2].setPosition(_rect.x+bl.x,_rect.y+bl.y);

    /**
        2nd triangle
    **/

    //Bottom left
    _dataPointer.vertices[3].setPosition(_rect.x+bl.x,_rect.y+bl.y);

    //Bottom right
    _dataPointer.vertices[4].setPosition(_rect.x+br.x,_rect.y+br.y);

    //Top right
    _dataPointer.vertices[5].setPosition(_rect.x+tr.x,_rect.y+tr.y);
}

Vector2<gamePos> Sprite::rotatePoint(Vector2<gamePos> pos, float& angle){

    Vector2<gamePos> newv;

    newv.x = pos.x * cos(angle) - pos.y * sin(angle);
    newv.y = pos.y * cos(angle) + pos.x * sin(angle);

    return newv;
}
```

And the result is [image: Image of problem]

Am i doing something wrong ? It happens also when i put small angle (even if i put here angle 1 )

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you sure the angle is supposed to be in degrees and not radians?

Comment: Man, you should really use shaders and matrices to rotate stuff around.

Comment: @Bálint Yes I know, but I wanted to try also this alternative.

Comment: @Pins this requires you to constantly load in new vertices to the gpu, and that's slow

Comment: @Bálint I thought that the thing with vertices is same, because I put every loop objects to spriteBatch(save vbo info + textureID) and buffer the data to GPU. Isn´t it right?

Comment: If your vbo is dynamic and you use that feature, then it still isn't. You only transmit the vertices once to the GPU, then you reference them when you draw them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
angle = angle *(3.14159/180.0)
newv.x = pos.x * cos(angle) - pos.y * sin(angle);
newv.y = pos.y * cos(angle) + pos.x * sin(angle);
```

Trig functions works with radians so you will have to do the conversion to radians as above. 
as stated in the comments, It is recommended you convert the `(3.14159/180.0)` to a constant and use the built in PI constant instead of 3.14159.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't work with anything, the trigonometric functions need radians

Comment: And try using built-in constants instead of 3.14159. Those usually go up to 20 decimal places.

Comment: @Bálint For the sake of argument - OpenGL **does** work with something. Old OpenGL functions, alike `glRotatef` worked with angles in degrees. Modern OpenGL shaders trig functions work with radians.

Comment: @Kromster If you count the deprecated stuff, then yes.